# Getting day from Datein Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to get the day of the week for a particular date, but the day that I am getting is not the right one. This is the part of my code

```
    SimpleDateFormat dayNameFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    date = "some date";
    daysName = dayNameFormat.format(sdf.parse(date);
```

Thanksin advance

Comment: If you use Java 8 read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.  DateFormat works fine if you use it correctly.  I'd also recommend looking at the new Java time package.  It's a big improvement.

Comment: What did you try? What is the output? What are the sources that you look before asking? Also a parenthesis is missing at the last line of the code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Prints FRIDAY...

```
    String dateString = "2016-12-02";
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
    DayOfWeek dow = localDate.getDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(dow);
```

Comment: Thank you, but is LocalDate class is available in jre7, because I am using jre7.

Comment: @dopeE - JSR-310 is the service request that adds the java.time libraries. This started in JDK 8, but there is a backport for JDK 7 available... http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/